# Convergence of Fourier Sine Series for Gerneral Continuous Function

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, uniform-convergence

This is my question:

> How do I should that, for $f \in C[0,\pi]$ with $f(0) = f(\pi) = 0$, the Fourier sine series $$\tilde f_n = \sum_{r=0}^n b_r \sin(r s)$$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0,\pi]$?

I would be able to do it given a specific $f$ (I would hope!), say by the Weierstrass M-Test, but I don't know how to in general. Also note that there is no differentiability condition on $f$.

This is part of a longer question, of which the first part is the same but for the cosine (without $f(\pi) = 0$) - the section is about polynomial approximation, and it asks me to use Chebyshev polynomials (of the first kind) and the Weierstrass approximation theorem. I just don't know how to adapt this to the sine case. Could I perhaps write $$F(x) = \int_0^x f(y) dy,$$ since $f$ is continuous and so integrable, and thus $F$ is continuously differentiable. I could then get a Fourier cosine series approximation for $F$, then differentiate term-by-term (as uniform convergence allows) to give the required answer. Would this be legitimate? (The issue is trying to differentiate through limits/inequalities...)

I have since gone through my above suggestion, and I believe it does work. My question is now the following:

> Is there a more direct method of doing this?

That is, it seems a slightly unusual way to go about answering the question, so is there a direct proof?

Thanks in advance for any help!

(PS - Sorry if this is similar to a duplicate question, although it's certainly not an exact duplicate!)

Comment: Are you doing this from "scratch" in the sense that all you have to work with is the definition of uniform convergence? Or do you have some convergence theorems at your disposal?

Comment: Good point. This is a Part II (third year) course. I can assume most stuff about uniform convergence - eg, uniform limit of continuous is continuous, Weierstrass M-test, etc - and similar such theorems. I can't, however, assume loads of stuff about Fourier analysis, as that is the point of this question! :)

Comment: If you are doing it from scratch, then you will need to reproduce several pieces of machinery along the way (that are too long for me to type out, sorry). Searching the web or a standard text like Churchill or Weinberger, etc. will lay out the plan.

Comment: No no, I said I can assume most stuff about convergence etc! The point of the question isn't that it's a Fourier series, but the point is to be using polynomial approximations.